# ¿Como convertir array multidimensional a plano con recursividad?

Tags: php

No logro llegar a un array plano. He intentado de 3 formas pero no comprendo que me falta aun.

```
class Clase{

public function metodo1($array){
      $arrayNuevo = [];
      for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
          if(gettype($array[$i]) != "array") {
              array_push($arrayNuevo, $array[$i]);
           }else{
              array_push($arrayNuevo, $this->metodo1($array[$i]));

          }
      }  
      return $arrayNuevo;      
}

public function metodo2($array){
      $arrayNuevo = [];
      function valores($arg,$crearArray){
          if(gettype($arg) != "array") {
              array_push($crearArray, $arg);
              return $crearArray;
           }
          for ($i = 0; $i < count($arg); $i++) {
              valores($arg[$i],$crearArray); 
          }
          return $crearArray;

      }
      valores($array,$arrayNuevo);
      return $arrayNuevo;
}

  public function metodo3($array){
      $arrayNuevo = [];
      for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
          if(gettype($array[$i]) != "array") {
              array_push($arrayNuevo, $array[$i]);
           }else{
              $this->metodo3($array[$i]);

          }
      }
  
      return $arrayNuevo;
      
  }

}
```

Ejemplo: El metodo toma un array [1,2,[3,4],[5,6,[7,8,[9,10]]]] y lo devuelve plano [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

El metodo 1 me devuelve el array sin cambios El metodo 2 un array vacio El metodo 3 devuelve un array con los elementos de primer nivel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Buen día.

Como etiquetas la palabra "lógica" en tú pregunta te la estoy respondiendo desde ese mismo punto de vista, pero utilizando Javascript en una función de aplanamiento y basado en esto podrías llevarlo, utilizando tu lógica a php, la idea es interactuar de forma recursiva dicho arreglo y aplicando reduce (que en php seria array_reduce).

Aquí el código basado en tu ejemplo:

```
    <script>
    
        var arreglo = [1,2,[3,4],[5,6,[7,8,[9,10]]]];
    
        function aplanar_arreglo(input){
            return input.reduce( function(inputArray , inputToFlat){
                return inputArray.concat(Array.isArray(inputToFlat) ? aplanar_arreglo(inputToFlat) : inputToFlat );
            }
            ,[]);
        }
        
        var arreglo_plano = aplanar_arreglo(arreglo)
        console.log(arreglo_plano);
        
    </script>
```

El Resultado aquí es -> Array(10) [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ]

Comment: Es justo lo que necesitaba. Mil gracias :)